# Attributes of values over time for Bayes classifier

Tags: analysis

I'm measuring acceleration over time. I want to collect a bunch of attributes of the measured values. Example, mean, max, min, standard deviation, time between peaks, etc. I'm not a math person and don't know what to look for to find out more options.

Could anyone give me more suggestions for attributes and/or suggest what I would call what I'm trying to do to get better answers from google?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try asking on http://stats.stackexchange.com/, they probably have more specific knowledge.